# Class special method behavior __complex__

Tags: python

I have a class that defines the `__complex__` special method. My class is not a standard numeric type (int, float, etc.), but it behaves like one as I have special methods defined for `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc.

I would like `__complex__` to return my complex valued numeric object, not a standard complex numeric value python expects. As such, Python throws the following error when I try to return my object, rather than a standard complex numeric.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'complex' and
>   'MyNumericClass'

What's the best way to do this?

---

Edit:

```
# Python builtins
import copy
# Numeric python
import numpy as np

class MyNumericClass (object):
    """ My numeric class, with one single attribute """
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __complex__(self):
        """ Return complex value """
        # This looks silly, but my actual class has many attributes other
        # than this one value.
        self._value = complex(self._value)
        return self

def zeros(shape):
    """
    Create an array of zeros of my numeric class

    Keyword arguments:
      shape -- Shape of desired array
    """
    try:
        iter(shape)
    except TypeError, te:
        shape = [shape]
    zero = MyNumericClass(0.)
    return fill(shape, zero)

def fill(shape, value):
    """
    Fill an array of specified type with a constant value

    Keyword arguments:
      shape -- Shape of desired array
      value -- Object to initialize the array with
    """
    try:
        iter(shape)
    except TypeError, te:
        shape = [shape]
    result = value
    for i in reversed(shape):
        result = [copy.deepcopy(result) for j in range(i)]
    return np.array(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_cplx = np.zeros(3).astype(complex)
    print a_cplx
    b_cplx = zeros(3).astype(complex)
    print b_cplx
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to guess what the problem might be without seeing the code.  Did you define `__rmul__()`?

Comment: Done. Please see the snippet. Thanks

Comment: I get `TypeError: __complex__ should return a complex object` after running your snippet. Perhaps you meant to return `self._value` instead of `self`? When I replace it, two lines are printed: `[ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]` and `[ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]`. I'm on Python 2.7.3.

Comment: If I return self._value it returns the attribute only. I want to return the entire object, so returning self._value is not what I want. That TypeError occurs because `__complex__(self)` wants a traditional complex numeric value returned and it chokes when I return the object. I'm not sure what the proper way is to achieve the functionality I desire. I was hoping I could use the special method to keep things python friendly, but perhaps this isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Define `__rmul__` (or define `__mul__` and flip the multiplication operands).
2. Cast your `MyNumericClass` instance to `complex` before multiplying.

Comment: Minor point: python doesn't have casts (where you tell the language that what's in memory is actually another type), you convert it into a brand new object (which can have memory/performance implications.)

Comment: I'm confused by your proposed solution. I'm not trying to multiply, I'm trying to return a complex valued object given a real. For example, I'd like to convert a real array of my objects to complex,
`x = mylib.zeros(shape).astype(complex)`
which would be similar to numpy
`x = np.zeros(shape).astype(complex)`
mylib.zeros creates an array of zeros of my custom numeric object, similar to numpy.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that causes the aforementioned TypError?